# Change footer style based on view height in react native

Tags: react-native

In react native, how would I go about applying a different footer style depending on the height of a particular ScrollView?

Basically, I want to create a sticky footer for a view that isn't the entire height of the phone and, if the ScrollView is larger, I want to add the footer onto the end of the ScrollView.

Hope that makes at least some sense!

Sample below for demonstration.

ThanksSimon

```
//If the view is larger than the phone height, have the footer at the bottom of the scroll view
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Header navigation={this.prop.navigation}
  <Scrollview>
    <View>
      <Text>Content</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Image source={image} style={styles.footerImage} />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>

//If the content view is smaller than the phone size, the view needs to be outside the scrollview and use stick styles
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Header navigation={this.prop.navigation}
  <Scrollview>
    <View>
      <Text>Content</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
  <View>
    <Image source={image} style={styles.stickyFooter} />
  </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footerImage: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    maxHeight: 235,
    resizeMode: "contain"
  },
  stickyFooter: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could move the footer position using `minHeight` on `Scrollview` css. Something like:

```
<Scrollview style={styles.scrollview}>
    <View>
      <Text>Content</Text>
    </View>
 </ScrollView>
```

Then in your styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    scrollview:{
       minHeight: 300   // 300 for example
    }
});
```

In this way, if `Scrollview` does not contains elements, footer appears after 300. Else, if `Scrollview` contains elements and his height is greater then 300, footer will be moved down according to `Scrollview` height.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text>Body</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text>Footer</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    minHeight: height, // This is where the magic happens
    backgroundColor: 'blue', // This is just for visual indication
  },
  footer: {
    minHeight: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'green' // This is just for visual indication
  }
});
```

Should work for different screen heights.